# remove a single overlay in googlemaps

Tags: jquery, overlay, google-maps

does anyone know if it is possible to remove the overlay where I previously drew a polygon? I don't want to use clearOverlays because it will remove all the markers also, instead I want to just  hide the markers.  Thanks, Richard

Comment: @richard: you have posted your question twice

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271120/remove-a-single-overlay-in-googlemaps

Comment: please delete your duplicates.

Comment: Why ask twice when once will do?

Comment: I can't see it anymore, maybe it's done for me?
Anyway, the penaltybox, what the hell was that for. I don't post duplicates (not on purpose anyway) I already emaild the SO team, because I at least deserve to know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Did you keep a reference to the overlay in question? Then just call map.removeOverlay()

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMap2

You question could be less conflicted. If you want to hide an overlay, say a marker, do as other poster said, hide() it.

polys *are* overlays, they are not married to markers, which are overlays as well.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, and I will try it out when I am home and not typing into my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the removeOverlay method of the GMap object?

```
removeOverlay(overlay:GOverlay)
```

[Link to related documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMap2.removeOverlay)

You can also just hide a marker without removing it from the map.

[Link to related documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMarker.hide)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the GoogleMaps References:

[GoogleMaps References](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMarker)

There you can find the function `hide()` which should do the job.